# How To startup Docker with phpmyadmin

Tags: docker, phpmyadmin, docker-compose

Hello guys im setting up my first Docker env im strugleling with the setup for phpmyadmin i would like to use the native phpmyadmin from docker hub and link it to my apache see the code bellow does anybody have few suggestions? how can i handle this issue.

```js
version: '2'
services:
  # PHP  Docker container
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    links:
      - mysql
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/app/
      - ./:/docker/
    volumes_from:
      - storage

#######################################
# MySQL server
#######################################
  mysql:
    build:
      context: docker/mysql/
      dockerfile: MySQL-5.7.Dockerfile
    restart: always
    volumes_from:
      - storage
    env_file:
      - etc/environment.yml

#######################################
# PHP MY ADMIN
#######################################
phpmyadmin:
  image:
  links:

  ports:
     - "8000:80"
  environment:
    MYSQL_USER: dev
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    
  storage:
    build:
      context: docker/storage/
    volumes:
      - /storage
```

```
MySQL Server Setup
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=dev
MYSQL_USER=dev
MYSQL_PASSWORD=dev
MYSQL_DATABASE=typo3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Docker-compose file you can have something like

```
phpmyadmin:
  image: phpmyadmin
  restart: always
  links:
    - mysql
  ports:
    - 8000:80
  environment:
    - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
  networks:
    - Your-network

networks:
    Your-network:
        driver: bridge
```

You have to add your network to all your services ( mysql, php , .. )

then you can access your phpmyadmin by go to localhost:8000

Comment: what u mean with networks ? :) im serving on http://192.168.99.100:8000/ i cant even use my localhost :( im also getting an error `yaml.parser.ParserError: while parsing a block mapping
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 35, column 2
expected <block end>, but found '<block mapping start>'
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 41, column 3`

Comment: kindly have a look https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

it's easy to setup just add network to your containers

Comment: added another complete version of docker compose , have a look

Comment: make sure you have right align for phpmyadmin under services like others

Comment: [link](https://codebeautify.org/yaml-validator/cb1e1cc4) it seems to be right idk what is wrong :( can u maybe take a look ?

Comment: remove the spaces ( tab ) before networks and storage

Answer (score 1):

Kindly find here complete version of docker compose file

```
version: '2'
services:
  # PHP  Docker container
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    links:
      - mysql
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/app/
      - ./:/docker/
    volumes_from:
      - storage
    networks:
      - php-network
#######################################
# MySQL server
#######################################
  mysql:
    build:
      context: docker/mysql/
      dockerfile: MySQL-5.7.Dockerfile
    restart: always
    volumes_from:
      - storage
    env_file:
      - etc/environment.yml
    networks:
      - php-network
#######################################
# PHP MY ADMIN
#######################################
phpmyadmin:
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: PHPMYADMIN.Dockerfile
  restart: always
  links:
    - mysql
  ports:
    - 8000:80
  environment:
    - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
  networks:
    - php-network

networks:
    php-network:
        driver: bridge
```

and PHPMYADMIN.Dockerfile will have only 1 line

```
FROM phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
```

and you can access phpmyadmin on 192.168.99.100:8000